# How to "sync" two project inside the same solution?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, project, solution

I've these project inside Visual Studio 2015:

[image]

as you can see, they "share" the same classes (.cpp/.h). If I edit it inside `DefaultProject-app`, automatically it change within `DefaultProject-vst2`.

Now, I want to make a new class, and I want the same for it. So right click to `DefaultProject-app`->Add->Class. But once I create it, it place only in `DefaultProject-app`. It should be in both project, and compile when I compile one of the other.

How can I do it? Somethings like "Build Phases" in Xcode?

Comment: Might it not be better to pull the shared files out into a third project, referenced by the other two?  That way you don't have to worry about keeping multiple copies around and keeping them in sync (even if VS is helping with that part).

Comment: What @senschen says. I usually make it a static library.

Comment: Maybe this is already the way this is "done" (third project referenced by the other two). But how can I know which is the "third" project where to put the new class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have classes that are used by more than one project, the best approach is to create a new third project that both `DefaultProject-app` and `DefaultProject-vst2` can both reference. This is one of the foundations of programming: a library with common classes and functions.

Comment: At the moment it seems already configured in this way, since once I edit a file, the others will be edited as well. But where do I see the "origin" source? Or maybe the files are just added using Add->Existing File within each project?

Comment: @markzzz If they were in a library, the .cpp files wouldn't be in both projects